# Custom font size with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to set the font size of bibliography to 9pt (my default font size is 12pt), which is not achievable with the default options (`small`, `scriptsize`, etc). I tried

```
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\fontsize{9}{11}}
```

and

```
\AtBeginBibliography{\fontsize{9}{11}}
```

but they only change some of the text in bibliography, which I don't understand. Is there a way to set all text to 9pt? Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Did you try using  `\AtBeginBibliography{\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont`?}

Comment: @Bernard Make that `\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}` or `\appto\bibfont{\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}` and turn it into an answer.

Comment: @moewe: I had forgotten this detail (I confess I don't use biblatex very often by now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @moewe in his comment, you should use

```
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}
```

or

```
\appto\bibfont{\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}
```